# R formatting, rounding, and truncating in print statement

Tags: r

How does R natively behave in a regular print statement of a floating-point number? Does it round, or truncate based on the computer's storage area? I am also aware of formatting a number in a print statement, so the case for my question is when one doesn't format the floating-point number.

Comment: The way R prints numbers is affected by [`options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html)`("digits")`. If you want more control, use `format` or `sprintf`.

Comment: If you need more, you'll need to make this question more actionable and *reproducible* by giving a clear example (sample data), code attempted, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: @r2evans The options thing answers my question I didn't know that was a thing in R.

Comment: @r2evans No because it your link had digits:

    "controls the number of significant (see signif) digits to print when printing numeric values. It is a suggestion only. Valid values are 1...22 with default 7. See the note in print.default about values greater than 15."  which is what I was looking for